# Add slide menu to activity in xamarin and android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

I want to create an with xamarin android application with a sliding menu in every activity, but with other values in every menu in different activities.

I could not find any code samples for SlidingDrawer or for Fragment.
Could someone please give me an XML and C# example for a sliding menu in an activity?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a sliding menu using android material design navigation drawer then this http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2016/01/navigation-drawer-using-material-design.html might be useful. same can also be implemented by using simple gesture recognition and animation, for detail you can check this my blog entry: http://appliedcodelog.com/2015/09/slidingflyout-in-menu-in-android.html.

Comment: This is a lot of Code. Do we really need to write all these Code? On the other Hand,  cant we write something in xamarin.forms to make it useable for Android and iphone?

Comment: @batmaci It's not a lot of code at all, to get an entire drawer menu that's an incredibly small amount of code.